# Inserting data into a Django ManyToMany field with intermediate table

Tags: python, django

I have an issue that I am unable to solve.  Here is the scenario:  there is a retail business which sells cigarettes.  This business can have many sites, but each site does not necessarily sell the same types of cigarettes.  For this reason, each store owner can browse to a web portal and select the cigarette types that their site sells – these selections will act as columns for a future table.  The trouble I am having is writing the data to a database because it is a ManyToMany field.  From the data entry perspective, everything appears to be working.  The user is able to select what they need and, as a test, I have a HttpResponse message that returns the correct value to the POST method of the view.

The problem that I’m running into is that I don’t know how to save this data in a table because the underlying table is part of a many-to-many relationship.  When I try to save the data coming from the form, I get an error:

**"Cannot assign "'6565'": "CigCountColumnsMappings.site_id" must be a "Sites" instance."**

I have tried many things and I just can’t seem to get this to insert.  I think this has something to do with the fact that site_id is a OneToOne/ForeignKey to the Sites model.

My models.py:

```
class Sites(models.Model):
    SITE_STATUS = (
        ('Open', 'Open'),
        ('Closed', 'Closed'),
        ('Maintenance', 'Maintenance')
    )

    id = models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name='Site ID', primary_key=True)

  def __str__(self):
        return self.id

class CigCountColumns(models.Model):
    column = models.CharField(max_length=10, primary_key=True, db_column="column", verbose_name="Column")

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.column)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["column", ]
        verbose_name = "Cigarette Count Column"
        verbose_name_plural = "Cigarette Count Columns"


class CigCountColumnsMappings(models.Model):
    site_id = models.OneToOneField('home.Sites', on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True, db_column="site_id", verbose_name="Site ID")
    columns = models.ManyToManyField(CigCountColumns, db_column="columns", verbose_name="Cig. Count Column Mappings", blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.site_id)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["site_id", ]
        verbose_name = "Cig. Count Column Mapping"
        verbose_name_plural = "Cig. Count Column Mappings"
```

My views.py:

```
def cigarette_columns(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        this_site = request.POST['this_site']
        choices = request.POST.getlist('choices')

        for choice in choices:
            record = CigCountColumnsMappings.objects.create(site_id=this_site, columns=choice)
            record.save()

        if choices:
            return HttpResponse([this_site, choices])
        else:
            return HttpResponse([this_site, "No data entered"])
```

The fact that site_id has a reference to the “home.Sites” table is messing me up.  I need to insert the values directly into the CigCountColumnsMappings model to map site 6565 to those particular columns but I am unable to do so.  I have taken a look at “through” models and read lots of documentation on ManyToMany fields but the solution still eludes me.  Many thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: What is the problem? What happens when you run this code? Do you get any errors? If so, what are they?

Comment: I'm confused by the naming here. You have a model class named `CigCountColumns` with a `CharField` named `column`. What does this have to do with "counts"? If I name something with "count" in my code, it is always a integer. But here you have a string instead. Should this be called `CigColumn` instead of `CigCountColumn`?

Answer (score 0):

First, change `site_id` to `site`. This will automatically create a field named `site_id` that is an integer value for the primary key.

Second, `columns` is a reference to `CigCountColumns`, but you assign it as `choices` which is a list. You need to create a `CigCountColumns` instance or get one from the database or have the id for a `CigCountColumns` before you create a `CigCountColumnsMappings`.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply.  I'm not sure I follow.  Changing site_id to site did nothing, and "choices" is a list of checkboxes that I'm getting from the web form, but I am using a for loop to separate out the values.  Therefore, "choice" is a single value.

Comment: @p98376 How do these "choices" relate to `CigCountColumns`?

Answer (score 0):

Just as an FYI, I was unable to resolve this issue in a pythonic Django way.  I ended up using Django raw SQL queries to hit the table directly (Google: "from django.db import connection") and this resolved it.  It's definitely not as "clean" as using the built-in Django methods, but it's not as dirty as completely bypassing Django and using pymysql either.